# Different results between browser and R mapdist (google API)

Tags: r, google-api, ggmap, readlines

I am using mapdist function from the ggmap package in R and I have a problem with results (more specifically by using the ReadLines function).
I give 2 addresses to the function, and then it connects to the Google API to return the distance between the 2 addresses. 
I give an example below without calling my real addresses.
The result is empty (Status: "Not_found") with R.

```
$destination_addresses
[1] "Adresse numero 1, France"

$origin_addresses
[1] ""

$rows
$rows[[1]]
$rows[[1]]$elements
$rows[[1]]$elements[[1]]
$rows[[1]]$elements[[1]]$status
[1] "NOT_FOUND"

$status
[1] "OK"
```

Given that I was sure of my address, I copied the URL (to connect on Google API) on my browser (I tried on Mozilla, Google Chrome and Internet explorer), and I was surprised to obtain a non-empty result.

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Adresse numero 1, France" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Adresse2, France" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "21,0 km",
                  "value" : 21045
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "17 minutes",
                  "value" : 1003
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

If I had only one address, the solution would be obvious. My problem is I have approximately 100 addresses with empty results and I can not check all of them.
How could you explain that the return result of ReadLines is not the same that the results on my webpage ?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The troubles I usually find with ggmap + R is the API does not understand the format.
I always fix this trouble checking the way google writes the address while using maps.googles.com and afterwards I make it reproductible.
I could try by my own if I could check it with real data, although you did not write it.
On the other hand you can subset all the "rows" google didn't give you the data back and try again.